# Wait for nested JS promise to finish before resolving original promise

Tags: javascript, promise, nested

I am new to Promises and I'm having a little trouble with the concept of waiting for a nested promise to finish all executions before resolving the original promise.

**Original Code**

```
function getSomething(text) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        getElse(text).then(function (items) {
            if (items.length !== 0) {

                /* Stuff here */

                getElseElse(box).then(function (moreItems) {

                    /* Stuff here */

                    return array;
                }.then(function (array) {
                    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        /* anotherFunction() is asynchronous */
                        result = anotherFunction(array); <-- Spot 1
                    });
                    promise.then(function () { });
                });

                return resolve(result); <--- Spot 2

            }
            else {
                return resolve(null);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**Updated Code** - better but still not fully working like I want.

```
function getSomething(text) {
    return getElse(text).then(function (items) {
        if (items.length !== 0) {

            /* Stuff here */

            return getElseElse(box).then(function (moreItems) {

                /* Stuff here */

                return array;
            }).then(anotherFunction);

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Then, inside of the individual View page, I have this:

```
getSomething(text).then(function (result) {
    /* Do something here using result */
    /* But result is undefined and I think still pending */
});
```

I have optimized the original function using Thomas's help but the original call inside the view still seems to be continuing before `result` is formulated.

I want `getSomething()` to full complete and return `result` before I execute the code inside of the `.then` that is inside the view. So far, that is not being accomplished.

I have found a couple posts that have pointed me in what I think is the correct direction of `Promise.all` but I can't really seem to get anywhere with that information so I was hoping someone could help explain it for my specific situation.

The posts that have helped are:

1. [Promise Chain not waiting for promises to resolve before ending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173220/promise-chain-not-waiting-for-promises-to-resolve-before-ending)
2. [Wait until nested promises resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529197/wait-until-nested-promises-resolve)
3. [Wait for promises inside Promise.all to finish before resolving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401703/wait-for-promises-inside-promise-all-to-finish-before-resolving-it)

## Solution

The original issue was solved by Thomas in the marked answer. The final problem was solved inside of `anotherFunction()` upon further inspection.

Originally:

```
function anotherFunction(array) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return anotherGet(parcels).then(function (list) {
            /* Do stuff here without a return */
        });
    });
}
```

Fixed Version:

```
function anotherFunction(array) {
    return anotherGet(parcels).then(function (list) {
        /* Do stuff here */
        return list;
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: I don't think you need to wrap that in a Promise in the first place; you're already getting a Promise back from `getElse()`; just return that. Similarly the `.then()` handler can return the `getElseBox()` Promise.

Comment: It's not clear in the question: is `anotherFunction()` asynchronous?

Comment: @MarkMeyer My apologies, but it is. I will add that to the post.

Comment: Updated question to hopefully better express issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, avoid the Promise/Deferred antipattern. Rarely you need to create your own promises, usually you have some function that returns a Promise; use that.

Second, for the outer Promise to wait for a nesed PRomise, you need to return that nested Promise to the outer Promise.
Returning a Promise inside of `then()` will make the resulting Promise to resolve to the value of the Promise you retuned inside.

And last, something like `.then(value => value)` or `.then(value => Promise.resolve(someFunction(value)))`is pointless. Your wrapper around `anotherFunction` basically just passed through the argument and returned the result.

So, your Pseudocode should look something like this:

```
function getSomething(text) {
  return getElse(text).then(function (items) {
    if (items.length !== 0) {
      /* Stuff here */
      return getElseElse(box).then(function (moreItems) {
        /* Stuff here */
        return array;
      }).then(anotherFunction);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What I want to return from the whole thing is *result*, not *array*. The reason i passed in *array* and returned *result* is because *array* is an array of lookups and *result* is a class generated from the lookups with more information. I need to pass *array* into *anotherFunction()* so that I can return the result from that function and I need to wait until the before items have finished before I execute *anotherFunction()* using *array*. That is the reason why I did that part how I did (might still be wrong haha). How  can I still return what I want using something like your sudo?

Comment: @Hank, as far as your snippet goes, `result = anotherFunction(array)`. That's exactly what `.then(anotherFunction);` does in my code.

Comment: Ok that clears things up, then. I didn't know the syntax worked in that way. I will try it out and let you know if it works like I want it to, which I believe it will. I had a strong feeling my code was mainly just inefficient lol

Comment: I updated the post with more information that I hope will help. It seems to be closer to what I want it to be with your recommendations but *getSomething().then()* appears to not be waiting on the result correctly.

Comment: Figured out the final problem and updated the post alongside marking your answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The basic trick is to make sure all of your `resolve()` calls are inside of the nested promises' `then()` methods.

Something along the lines of:

```
function getSomething(text) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        getElse(text).then(function (items) {
            if (items.length !== 0) {

                /* Stuff here */

                getElseElse(box).then(function (moreItems) {

                    /* Stuff here */

                    return array;
                }.then(function (array) {
                    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        result = anotherFunction(array); <-- Spot 1
                    });
                    promise.then(function () { });

                    resolve(result); <--- Spot 2
                });    
            }
            else {
                resolve(null);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

If it needs to be nested in the `promise.then()` above, just stick it in there instead.

Also note that you don't need to return your resolves. Just call them.