# Knex.js with Express, How can I knex.commit followed by a knex.select query?

Tags: javascript, sql, express, knex.js

I am trying to do a post request that will do the following.

1. Update the database
2. Commit the update
3. Return the new record in the JSON reponse

Here is the code I have, it works to update the dataase, I threw in some console.logs() to see the flow.
the current code outputs "World Hello" instead of "Hello World".  How could I make the output be "Hello World" ?

```
app.post('/checkin', async (req, res) => {
db('assets').select('status').where('id', '=', req.body.id)
    .then(data => {
        currentStatus = data[0].status;
        if (currentStatus.slice(0, 10) === 'In Use By ' || currentStatus === 'Quarantine') {
            db('assets')
                .where('id', '=', req.body.id)
                .update({ status: 'Available', comments: '' }).then(db.commit) 
                .then(console.log('Hello'))   
        }
    })
    .then(console.log('World')) 
    .then(db('assets').select('*').where('id', '=', req.body.id)
        .then(data => res.status(200).json(data[0])))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json(error))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add in a return on the inner promise, that should fix things. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54010690/5774952) for details on why. You could also refactor things a bit to use `await` (right now your `async` keyword is going to waste), which would un-nest the blocks, and clarify the flow. Note: this code is not tested, but it's just changing your code to use async/await so I *think* it will work:

```
app.post('/checkin', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await db('assets').select('status').where('id', '=', req.body.id)
    currentStatus = data[0].status;

    if (currentStatus.slice(0, 10) === 'In Use By ' || currentStatus === 'Quarantine') {
      await db('assets')
        .where('id', '=', req.body.id)
        .update({ status: 'Available', comments: '' })

      await db.commit();
      console.log('Hello');
    }

    console.log('World')
    const secondData = await db('assets').select('*').where('id', '=', req.body.id)
    res.status(200).json(secondData[0])
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(error)
  }
});
```